# PHP COOKIE subdomain to domain not working

Tags: php, cookies, cross-domain, subdomain

I have used following code for cookie but its not working for domain.

```
setcookie('cookiename', 'value', time() + 3600,"/",'.domain.com');

setcookie('cookiename', 'value', time() + 3600,"/",'subdomain.domain.com');

setcookie('cookiename', 'value', time() + 3600,"/");
```

header("Set-Cookie: cookiename=cookievalue; expires=Tue, 06-Jan-2019 23:39:49 GMT; path=/; domain=subdomain.example.net");

All above 4 examples are not working cookie from subdomain to domain. Please help.

Comment: you can use `header("Set-Cookie: cookiename=cookievalue; expires=Tue, 06-Jan-2019 23:39:49 GMT; path=/; domain=subdomain.example.net");`

Comment: used still not working.